# Can I use set_param in matlab to change global variable

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to change value of global variable during simulation run.
I found something called set_param() but I cant figure out how it work.
Lets say there is variable A I want to update inside interpreted matlab function.
So I did.

```
set_param('mySimulation','A',A);
```

but it says `block_diagram does not have a parameter named 'A'` but A is global variable.
What should I do?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo that you but I think thats not solution to my problem.